# Hibernate L2 caching using memcached

Tags: hibernate, memcached

I am trying to use memcached for Hibernate Level 2 caching but haven't been able to get it working yet. I am running into the following exception(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/TimestampsRegion) when I fire up the tomcat and launch my application :

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:119)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.MemberFilter.doFilter(MemberFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.LanguageHandlingFilter.doFilter(LanguageHandlingFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.SsoFilter.doFilter(SsoFilter.java:72)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.SessionStatusFilter.doFilter(SessionStatusFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.BlackListFilter.doFilter(BlackListFilter.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.xxx.webapp.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/TimestampsRegion
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:393)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:264)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
atorg.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
```

I am using JPA with hibernate 4.1.7 as the provider. My persistence.xml properties for hibernate L2 caching look like :

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> 
         <property name="hibernate.Memcached.servers" value="localhost:11211"/>
         <property name="hibernate.Memcached.cacheTimeSeconds" value="300"/>
```

I am using following versions of jar files related to hibernate and memcached :

memcached-2.3.1.jar
hibernate-memcached-1.6.jar (compiled from the source from com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached project)
slf4j-1.5.0.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar

I haven't been able to get around this problem yet. Any help from you guys is greatly appreciated.

Arun

Answer (score 3):

I know this is three years old but this is still very relevant. You can use memcached (or any memcache clone like elasticache) in Hibernate 4 and 5. We do so with 4 ourselves.

You can obtain the proper jar via this gradle dependency:

`compile 'com.github.mihaicostin:hibernate-l2-memcached:1.1.0'`

or Maven: 

    `<groupId>com.github.mihaicostin</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-l2-memcached</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>`

it is up to date and works very well. Open source on github.
https://github.com/mihaicostin/hibernate-l2-memcached

As an example a snippet from our persistence.xml at Bjond. Note that you want that region factory:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.bjond.persistence.converter.JsonPostgreSQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>

     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />    
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.REGION.cacheTimeSeconds" value="30"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.mc.hibernate.memcached.MemcachedRegionFactory"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.operationTimeout" value="5000"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.connectionFactory" value="KetamaConnectionFactory"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.hashAlgorithm" value="HashAlgorithm.FNV1_64_HASH"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.servers" value="localhost:11211"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.cacheTimeSeconds" value="300"/>
     <property name="hibernate.memcached.clearSupported" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/> 
     <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your are using Hibernate 4. To use hibernate-memcached you should have HB3. See hibernate-memcached configuration here : https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Yes I am using hibernate 4. Is the memcached not supported with HB4? Is there no workaround?